# Trim user agent browser version number

Tags: codeigniter

I am using the build in Codeigniter Agent detection library and that outputs
the browser version. The only problem is that it outputs the complete version number.

For example this for Chrome:

```
16.0.912.77
```

I only need this:

```
16
```

How can I trim away everything after 16? It must work for other browser versions too.
Like 7.44.3.

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
$version = '16.0.912.77';

$shortVersion = explode('.', $version);
$shortVersion = $shortVersion[0];

echo $shortVersion; // will output <16>
```